# Minimum cabs required (Algorithm)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve this question:

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/greedy/basics-of-greedy-algorithms/practice-problems/algorithm/minimum-cabs-0798cfa5/description/

I see a solution here but I don't quite understand it.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int MAX = 1500;
int A[MAX];
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc == 2 or argc == 3) freopen(argv[1], "r", stdin);
    if(argc == 3) freopen(argv[2], "w", stdout);
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n, hh1, hh2, mm1, mm2, smins, emins, ans;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> hh1 >> mm1 >> hh2 >> mm2;
        smins = hh1 * 60 + mm1;
        emins = hh2 * 60 + mm2;
        A[smins]++;
        A[emins+1]--;
    }
    ans = A[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX; i++) {
        A[i] += A[i-1];
        ans = max(ans, A[i]);
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Could someone explain the algorithm to me?

Answer (score 2):

The given solution works on maximum overlapping intervals.

The author wants to count the maximum number of intervals or ranges which overlap at any given point in the time.

Assume a time scale, which represents time:

Min time: 00:00 => represents 0 on the time scale

Max time: 23:59 => represents 1439 on the time scale

So, author used a constant `MAX` as 1500, thus making a time scale of [0, 1500], which satisfies our requirement.

Now, for each interval/ range we got from the input, author made use of prefix sum, thus adding 1 to every time unit in the range.

For eg: Suppose my range is 00:00 to 12:36, then I will add 1 to every index of array `A` from 0 to 756.

**The maximum prefix sum denotes the minimum number of cabs required as 1 cab can be only be allocated to 1 person at any particular instance of time.**

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask any doubts. Kindly mark answer correct if satisfies your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[24*60+1];

        while(t!=0)
        {
            int st = sc.nextInt()*60+sc.nextInt();
            int et = sc.nextInt()*60+sc.nextInt();

            for(int i=st;i<=et;i++)
            {
                arr[i]++;
            }
            t--;
        }

        int max=0;

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            max=Math.max(max,arr[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```